# Problem with viewing interactive PDF content on Mac

Tags: pdftex, viewers, online, adobe

I use packages such as `popupmenu` and `fancytooltips` on a Windows system using PDFLaTeX to create some interactive PDF texts to be posted online. The resulting documents behave as expected when viewed from a browser in Windows system. But when I view them on a Mac Machine none of the interactivity works. I know that the viewer should be Adobe as most other PDF viewers do not have the necessary support. But I am not sure what else I could be missing.

Edit 1

Here are two files where I try to use `fancytooltip` package

File 1  (This is saved as mathtipsdemo.tex and compiled)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{yellow!50}
\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{document}
\savebox\mybox{%
\Huge$\displaystyle M= \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & \beta   \\
\gamma & \delta  \\
\end{bmatrix}$%
}
\keytip{M}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\wd\mybox}
\begin{shaded}
\usebox\mybox
\end{shaded}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

File 2, this is compiled separately from File 1. Then the PDF output is viewed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[filename=mathtipsdemo,mouseover,noextratext]{fancytooltips}
\begin{document}
 Instructions: Hover on the formula.

 Consider the matrix \tooltip{$M= \begin{bmatrix}
 \alpha & \beta   \\
 \gamma & \delta  \\
 \end{bmatrix}$}{M}.
 \end{document}
```

I process this with PDFLaTeX on  Windows. It works as expected when viewed from a Windows machine. But when viewed from a Mac machine it produces odd results.

I placed the output PDF file on  [this site](http://lumath.pbworks.com/w/page/19565930/FrontPage).

Edit 2

[Here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3282194#3282194) is perhaps a somewhat similar problem report on Adobe Reader forum.

Comment: Which viewer are you using on the Mac?

Comment: I believe I directed Mac to open the document with Adobe Reader.

Comment: You could always give our PDF Viewer a try if you're having difficulties with Adobe: http://bfo.com/products/pdfviewer/

Comment: @JonathanCookson: "Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam." (from [FAQ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion))

Comment: @PolGab I converted it to a comment. As the affiliation is disclosed and it's a suggestion regarding the problem, I don't see a problem to have it here.

Comment: @Maesumi --- please edit your question and add a short example code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @IanThompson I added an example.

Comment: A similar report was posted on Adobe Reader site which I linked to under Edit 2 above.

Comment: @Maesumi I downloaded your PDF; if I point with the mouse over the matrix, the yellow box appears. Reader 9.5.1

Comment: @egreg  Is this opened inside Safari, another browser, or without browser?

Comment: @Maesumi With Adobe Reader.

Comment: This problem seems to have been caused by a faulty installation of Adobe. My apologies, and thanks everyone.